# How does one limit rate of api calls despite page reload?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Suppose I am using a free API service with a limit of **c** calls per **m** minutes.

I am using a tiny bit of javascript linked by the main html of my very basic site which contains something like the following:

```
$(function () { 

//stuff

    function getSomething() {
        return $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: targetURL,
           data: dataObject,
        });
    }

    getSomething().done(function (returnedStuff){
        //process returnedStuff
    });

//more stuff

});
```

I have two questions:

- Will there be an api call each time the page is reloaded?
- If the answer to above is `YES`, then how does one prevent/limit the user/some other event from overshooting the api limit by their repeated reloading of the page.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using anything like php or asp.net?

Comment: When do you call getSomething()?

Comment: The answer to the first point is YES, about the second point: you can "prevent" (not really, because it's javascript, hence he can call it whenever he wants) the user from overshooting the api by using something like a cookie or local storage in such a context. Also, keep in mind that you're running the script on the **client's machine**, hence you're limiting **his** calls to the api, not **yours**. However, if he want to fetch the api every single time, he can do that without your permission. To just prevent him from fetching again, anyway, I would use a cookie or a localstorage object.

Comment: (also, I suppose your are calling the getSomething function at least ONCE somewhere in your page when the DOM is loaded)

Comment: I'll elaborate, since everyone is missing a very simple solution.  If you can write a proxy type function on your web server then you can simply write a web method that calls the API and that can cache the data (unless it changes every time) and return that cached data for any calls above the imposed API limit.

Comment: @briosheje Should I just rethink this and just use curl?

Comment: @sntx: Absolutely not necessarely. You can do that in whatever way you like but, because the javascript side is built already, I would use a cookie or localstorage, that's the fastest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tldr:** Making some assumptions from your high level example:

- Will there be an api call each time the page is reloaded? **Yes**
- If the answer to above is YES, then how does one prevent/limit the
  user/some other event from overshooting the api limit by their
  repeated reloading of the page. **Read below**

**Further explanation:**
Depending on whether your example code hits your own server side code which then makes the API code...or whether you're calling the API directly from the client. If you call the function on reload (document ready or whatever), then it will execute on every reload. Else, obviously only when you call the method (like via button click).

Remember, client side code is visible to the client - thus if that's your architecture, then you're exposing your API to the client. I can then for example write my own javascript to loop and call your API repeatedly...

My assumption is that the data does not need to refresh on every reload. With that in mind, I suggest you do the following:

**Suggested way to limit API calls:**
Use an ajax call to your own server.
On the server side, persist the data via caching of your choice and build in your own logic to test whether data needs to be refreshed (first call, after timeout, etc).

This way you do not expose the API url and details to the client side, and you have control over the amount of calls made to the API.

For optimization purposes, you can also rather cache data client side...but keep the logic and API call server side.

Hope this helps!

**ps.** If you need an example, please just provide what platform you're coding in and I'll be more than willing to whip up a quick example for you!

**pps.** You can simply cache client side and makde the API call from there with some logic built in to test the cache - but obviously anyone can then still call your API.